# 'Following' an object

Tags: java, python, sql, nosql, nlp

I am trying to develop a real-time feed, and have run into a dilemma. I have the standard event, with a user as the subject -

- **Person** is now **action**. [ For example, "**John** is now **connected with Steve**". ]

This event occurs when a person that I am following does something.

In addition, I also have an event that is dependent on a non-user object, a "production" -

- **Production** is now **action** [ For example, **Titanic** now **includes Kate Winslet in its credits**.

In other words, users can follow other 1) users or 2) productions. However, the two events may butt into each other. Suppose the following example.

1)

- David is not following the user Steve.
- David is following the production Titanic
- Titanic has a new event, which involves the user Steve.
- Since David is following Titanic and not Steve, David;s feed will say something like:
     "**Titanic** now includes **Steve** in its credits".
- Now David starts following Steve, the above grammar works but suppose this case:

2)

- David is following Steve now, but not Titanic.
- Steve joins the production Titanic. On David's feed would say something like:
  "**Steve** joined the production **Titanic**".
- Now David starts following the Titanic, the above grammar works, but is in conflict with 1) based upon the ordering of events.

It seems this is why sites like Facebook/LinkedIn **always** have a single consistent object as the subject of the event (a user, in their cases).

Would it be possible to have both a user and a production? I know it would be more difficult, but how could it be done?

Comment: Ummm... sorry I´m being really dumb. Where exactly is the conflict between (1) and (2) -- aren't they different cases? And if you have two different types of cases that need different 'grammar'... so what? What's your actual problem in programming terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would it be possible to have both a user and a production?

Several ways:

- Database:  set or clear status flags (in action or not)
- Python:  either multiple inheritance with status flags or use composition with delegation
- Java: composition with delegation

Another way to think about the problem is to use [role-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-oriented_programming) techniques.